# Jquery form plugin not submitting to process page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a basic contact form that uses the Jquery form plugin. I cannot get it to submit using the plugin. It only submits if I add a php include to process.php.

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#contact").validate({
         submitHandler: function(form) {
             $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                 url:"process.php",
                 type:"post",
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

And here is my contact form:

```
 <form id="contact" method="post" name="validation" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
     <fieldset> 

         <label for="name">Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Enter your name" class="required">

         <label for="email">E-mail</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" title="Enter your e-mail address" class="required email">

         <label for="phone">Phone</label>
         <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="ex. (555) 555-5555">

         <label for="message">Question/Comment</label>
         <textarea name="message"></textarea>

         <input type="submit" name="submitted" class="button" id="submit" value="Send Message"     />

     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Process.php

```
   <?php
   function GetHeaders()
   {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: Company Name<info@companyname.com>' . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
   }
   // Get Data  
   $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
   $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
   $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
   $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    // Send Message
    $headers = GetHeaders();
    $intro = "\"Thank you for contacting Company Name. We are very interested in assessing your situation and will be in touch as soon possible.\" <br />
    <br/>
      Best Regards,<br/>
    <br/>
      Company<br/>
    ";
 mail($email, "RE: Contact Form Submission", $intro, $headers);      
 ?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what's content of `process.php`?

Comment: I added it above, but it seems as though it is not even reaching process.php. When using include("process.php"); I can get everything to work, but I really wanted to get a grip on why the form plugin isn't working. I am also using jquery 1.8.0

Comment: in html `action='contact.php'` and in ajax `url: 'process.php'` makes me confuse

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `onsubmit="return validateForm();` from your form attributes.  You are already validating using `$("#contact").validate({` in your query ready function

Also, your form seems to be submitting to contact.php, not process.php

```
action="contact.php"
```

Comment: thanks, hsalama-- I thought the plugin overrides the action on the form, i.e. contact.php? I do not want the user to go to process.php after the form is submitted, I want them to remain on contact.php